Does the Dispose of my Activity run synchronously to my application code?
Here is a method which creates an Activity, populates some random data into the Activity and then Disposes of the Activity via the using construct. (Don't look for a whole lot of meaning to this. I'm just learning how to use this.)
At the bottom, you can see I am measuring how long it takes to wrap up the using block. There is NO code statement of mine between the sw.Start and sw.Stop, simply the exit from the using block.
What I am seeing, is that when the target endpoint is not available, it takes about 4,000ms to complete the Disposal of the Activity. I don't want the export of the telemetry to degrade the performance of my application. How can I insulate my application from the impact of the telemetry export under an adverse scenario when the target endpoint is not responding properly?
    private static void OnePass(int Counter)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        using (var actv = m_activitySource.StartActivity("OnePass"))
        {
            actv.AddEvent(new ActivityEvent("Start OnePass()"));
            actv.SetTag("counter", Counter);
            actv.SetTag("markstart", DateTime.Now.ToString());
            actv.AddEvent(new ActivityEvent("Finisehd OnePass()"));
            actv.SetTag("markfinish", DateTime.Now.ToString());
            actv.SetStatus(Status.Ok);

            sw.Start();
        }
        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Milliseconds: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }

EDIT: Here are the details of the target telemetry collector: We have tested this code against two endpoints using http/Protobuf. The first endpoint is a trivial webservice which I wrote myself to simply catch the body of the post and write it out to a logfile. This simply confirms that the client is correctly exporting the telemetry. The second target is an Azure Open Telemetry collector. In both instances the same behavior is observed. When the target endpoint is not available, my application blocks for several seconds on each trace (activity) export. My understanding is that the architecture of OTel is designed so that the export of telemetry would be a non-blocking operation. It could either succeed quickly, succeed slowly or fail outright but that in no instance would it slow down the execution of the application which is exporting the telemetry. Is this not the case? Does introducing telemetry introduce a new bottleneck / failure point into my application processing?
EDIT: Here is the code which sets up the Trace Provider:
    internal static TracerProvider GetTracerProvider(string service, string version, bool consoleExporter, bool OtlpExporter)
    {

        TracerProviderBuilder tpb = Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
                .AddSource(service)
                .SetResourceBuilder(
                ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault()
                .AddService(serviceName: service, serviceVersion: version));

        if (consoleExporter)
        {
            tpb.AddConsoleExporter();
        }

        if (OtlpExporter)
        {
            tpb.AddOtlpExporter
                (exp =>
                {
                    exp.Endpoint = new Uri((AppConfig.GetAppSetting("OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT_BASE").TrimEnd('/')
                                           + "/"
                                           + AppConfig.GetAppSetting("OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT_TRACES").TrimStart('/')).TrimEnd('/'));
                    exp.Protocol = (OtlpExportProtocol) Convert.ToInt16(AppConfig.GetAppSetting("OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_PROTOCOL", "1"));
                    exp.ExportProcessorType = (ExportProcessorType) Convert.ToInt16(AppConfig.GetAppSetting("OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_EXPORT_TYPE", "0"));
                    exp.BatchExportProcessorOptions = new BatchExportProcessorOptions<Activity>()
                    {
                        MaxQueueSize = Convert.ToInt16(AppConfig.GetAppSetting("OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_MAX_QUEUE", "2048")),
                        ScheduledDelayMilliseconds = Convert.ToInt16(AppConfig.GetAppSetting("OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_SCHED_DELAY", "5000")),
                        ExporterTimeoutMilliseconds = Convert.ToInt16(AppConfig.GetAppSetting("OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_TIMEOUT", "1000")),
                        MaxExportBatchSize = Convert.ToInt16(AppConfig.GetAppSetting("OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_MAX_BATCH", "512")),
                    };
                });
        }

        return tpb.Build();
    }

Here are the relevant config parameters:
<!-- OTEL Configuration -->
<add key="ExportTelemetry" value="0"/>
<add key="OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT_BASE" value="http://localhost:58234/Telemetry" />
<add key="OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT_METRICS" value="v1/metrics" />
<add key="OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT_TRACES" value="v1/traces" />
<add key="OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT_LOGS" value="v1/logs" />
<add key="OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_HEADERS" value="" />
<add key="OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_TIMEOUT" value="300" />
<add key="OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_MAX_QUEUE" value="2048" />
<add key="OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_SCHED_DELAY" value="5000" />
<add key="OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_MAX_BATCH" value="512" />

<!-- Grpc = 0, Http/Protobuf = 1 -->
<add key="OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_PROTOCOL" value="1" />   
<!-- Simple = 0, Batch = 1 -->
<add key="OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_EXPORT_TYPE" value="0" />


You'll need to provide a bit more context for anybody to help you with this. How exactly are you integrating your application with an external telemetry backend? Are you using OpenTelemetry? How does the setup code look like? Where are you exporting telemetry data to?

Keep in mind OpenTelemetry relies on a hosted service to asynchronously handle and send telemetry data it captures from the application, so what you are seeing here should not be happening as far as I know. But again, this will depend on how exactly you are integrating with OTEL, and what type of application we are talking about here (web api, service, cmdline tool, etc).

@julealgon I edited the question to include details about the target endpoint. If more detail is needed I will be happy to supply.

@julealgon I also added the code which sets up the trace provider. Let me know if there are any additional details which are relevant to the question.

Ok you have a lot of stuff... my first initial suggestion would be to trim down your case to try and identify which part is causing the behavior you are seeing. For instance, removing your custom exporter would be a good start, as well as the console exporter. I see as well that you are using a value of 0 (Simple) for OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_EXPORT_TYPE while the actual default is 1 (Batch). Changing that and seeing if that changes your behavior is another test.

Could you also share the versions you are using of each of the OTEL packages? And have you considered leveraging the OpenTelemetry.Extensions.Hosting abstractions instead of dealing with the TraceProvider manually yourself using the raw SDK? OpenTelemetry.Extensions.Hosting should result in a simpler (and less error-prone) setup so I'd strongly recommend it.

@julealgon Wow! Changing from Simple to Batch made all the difference in the world. The prototype is now flying with no performance penalty, even though the target endpoint is not running. I'll run some more testing in my prototype and then I'll do some more testing in production. I'll confirm later on. This may be the solution!

Glad to see that made a significant difference! Let me know so I can add it as an answer once you've confirmed it is working as expected.

@julealgon I can confirm that switching to OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_EXPORT_TYPE = 1 (Batch) is exactly what we need to isolate the application layer from the collector. We turned the collector off for two hours today and observed no ill effects to the application. If you post that as the answer I'll accept that to your credit. Thanks!

The issue you are seeing is due to how the Simple (value 0) export type works: it will immediately and synchronously attempt to publish telemetry as soon as it is emitted by the listener when the Activity is disposed. I noticed you were using Simple mode in your settings but also noticed it is not the default: the default is actually Batch, which has value 1.
Batch mode will manage a queue that is emptied in the background from time to time (configurable), so it becomes an asynchronous process decoupled from your code execution.
As a general suggestion with OTEL, I would always recommend starting with the default configuration, and only fine tune the settings that make sense for your particular use case. This is because there are many different settings that can substantially impact how generation and ingestion of data behaves. This can even impact the receiving observability platform (we had issues with Datadog ourselves when doing the integration initially that required setting changes).
As a sidenote, it is unusual for an enum to default to its non-zero element. I wonder why they opted for this.
